# oracle php rollback with multiple table

Tags: php, oracle

I am trying to insert a table with some fields

```
$ecode = 1000; 
$location = 'B'; 
$file_id = 1; 
$accessed_on = '30-NOV-14';
```

my code is

```
$conn = oci_connect('username', 'passwd', '//server/db');    
if (!$conn) {    
    $e = oci_error();    
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);    
} else {     
}    

$query_Test = "
    insert into example(ECODE,LOCATION,FILE_ID,ACCESSED_ON) 
    values($ecode,'$location',$file_id,'$accessed_on')";   

$parse_Test = oci_parse($conn, $query_Test);    
if(oci_execute($parse_Test)) {
    echo 'Success';        
    $query_Test1 = "
        update example     
        set ACCESSED_ON=03-nov-14,    
        where LOCATION='B'";    

    $parse_Test1 = oci_parse($conn, $query_Test1);    

    if(oci_execute($parse_Test1)){      
        oci_rollback($conn);    
    }    
}
```

but which doesnot rollback query_Test when query_Test1 fails.how to do this.someone help.thanks in advance

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php <- docs. They're important. Check them out.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-rollback.php might be this will also help

Answer (score 0):

When you write the oci_execute($test,OCI_DEFUALT); 
It will work.

because if you didnt define any second parameter its AUTO COMMIT by defualt 
By defining this parameter its no auto commit (oci_defualt) or (OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT )

And the reason why its not rolledback 
You cannot rollback if you commited(save) your state.